# Looking for output of code line by line in the right window in Xcode but it isn't there

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground

I'm not completely sure how to ask this because I don't know what it is called. I am looking for the window on the right that shows the output of the code as you type it line by line. It isn't showing up and I'm not sure how to make it appear.

My view:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Shift + Command + C` will show the console

> I am looking for the window on the right that shows the output of the
>   code as you type it line by line.

You might be looking for the playground output area which means you should open a playground instead of a project.
[image]

Comment: thats right, is there anyway to view that in a project? I'm still learning xcode and swift